# Angular ui-grid - How to reset the state of edited rows

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have a ui-grid in my page. I am allowing row edit, few cells in each row are editable. I have a save button and on click of that button I am getting all the dirty rows by `$scope.grid1Api.rowEdit.getDirtyRows();`  I am taking these dirty row values to the server by $http post request. Once the request is served successfully Again I am retrieving the fresh data from DB and setting it to the grid like `$scope.mygrid.data = recentData;` Now the grid shows the recent data. If i try to get the dirty rows now, it should not return any rows. But it returns the old edited rows

If any ideas, please share it.

Comment: AngularJs' 2-way data binding? Shouldn't you try to reset the ng-models you used in the form if a 200 response is returned from the HTTP request?

Comment: @manu29.d Yes. It is two way binding as per my understandings. Please let me know what you mean by resetting ng-models. As i am new i am struggling to find a way to reset the state of row entities to clean state.

Comment: I think you should look at [official documentation of ng-submit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit#example). See what they're doing after the text is pushed to the array.

Answer (score 1):

After successful http post, you can clear the array of dirty rows:

`scope.gridRows = scope.gridApi.rowEdit.getDirtyRows();
 var dataRows = scope.gridRows.map(function (gridRow) { return gridRow.entity; });
 scope.gridApi.rowEdit.setRowsClean(dataRows);`

Comment: `console.log('dirty rows:'+$scope.grid1Api.rowEdit.getDirtyRows().length);  
   $scope.gridRows = $scope.grid1Api.rowEdit.getDirtyRows();
   var dataRows = $scope.gridRows.map(function (gridRow) { return gridRow.entity; });
   $scope.grid1Api.rowEdit.setRowsClean(dataRows);
   //$scope.grid1Api.rowEdit.setRowsClean($scope.grid1Api.rowEdit.getDirtyRows());  
   console.log('dirty rows:'+$scope.grid1Api.rowEdit.getDirtyRows().length);`


This works - the direct approach (commented out) doesn't.